# How to show full post?

Tags: posts, the-content

I'm using [this theme](http://themeforest.net/item/magazine/5999747?WT.ac=category_item&WT.seg_1=category_item&WT.z_author=vickystudio) for my magazine website. I'm having trouble showing the full content on my blog side. I have tried changing in the php to `show_content` but it doesn't work. Any suggestions on how to solve this

This is the page code:

```
<?php 
/* Template Name: Home 5 */
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<!--<home 5>-->

<!--<div tm_category 0>-->
<div class="tm_category_0">
<!--</div tm_middle 0>-->

    <!--<category name>-->
    <div class="tm_cat_metatitle">
        <h1>
            <i class="icon-reorder"></i> 
             Recent Posts           
        </h1> 
        <div class="tm_cat_arrow"></div>
    </div>
    <!--</category name>-->

    <!--<tm_category_file>-->
    <div class="tm_category_file">
        <div class="tm_category_box_home5">

        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

            <!--<the loop>-->
            <?php $wp_query = new WP_Query( array( 
                                                "cat" => "", 
                                                "posts_per_page" => "", 
                                                "post_type" => "post",
                                                "paged" => get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1
                                                )                                               
                                        );
            while( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

            <div <?php post_class(); ?>>

                <!--<cat title>-->
                <div class="tm_catpost_titles">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                            <h1 class="tmpost-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                            <?php $tit = the_title('','',FALSE); echo substr($tit, 0, 150); if (strlen($tit) > 150) echo " ..."; ?>
                            </h1>
                        </a>
                </div>
                <!--</cat title>-->     

                <!--<cat item>-->
                <div class="tm_cat_item">
                    <div class="tmpost-<?php the_ID(); ?>-item">

                        <div class="tm_catpost_item_1">
                        <i class="icon-user"></i> 
                        <?php _e('By', 'tm_myid_text'); ?> <?php the_author(); ?>
                        </div>

                        <div class="tm_catpost_item_2">
                        <i class="icon-tag"></i> 
                        In <?php $category = get_the_category(); echo $category[0]->cat_name; ?>
                        </div>

                        <div class="tm_catpost_item_3">
                        <i class="icon-calendar"></i>
                        <?php the_time('M jS, Y') ?>
                        </div>

                        <div class="tm_catpost_item_4">
                        <i class="icon-comments"></i> 
                        <?php comments_number(__('0 Comments', 'tm_myid_text'), __('1 Comment', 'tm_myid_text'), __( '% Comments', 'tm_myid_text') );?>
                        </div>

                        <div class="tm_catpost_item_5">
                        <i class="icon-eye-open"></i> 
                        <?php echo tm_viewcounter_display(get_the_ID()); ?>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--</cat item>-->

                <!--<cat image>-->
                <div class="tm_cat_image">
                <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) { ?>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'Full' ); ?>
                    </a>
                <?php } else { ?>
                <?php } ?>
                </div>
                <!--</cat image>-->

                <div class="tm_cat_desc_home5">
                    <div class="tmpost-desc">
                    <?php echo excerpt(500); ?> 
                    </div>

                    <div class="tm_cat_readmore">
                        <div class="tmpost-readmore">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                                <i class="icon-file-text"></i> 
                                <?php _e('Kommentera', 'tm_myid_text'); ?>
                            </a>
                            <div class="tmpost-readmore_list"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <!--</the loop>-->

        </div>
    </div>
    <!--</tm_category_file>-->

    <!--<tm pagination>-->
    <div id="Nav">
        <div class="tm_navigation">
        <?php echo tm_pagination_nav(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--</tm pagination>-->

        <?php else : ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

</div>

<!--</home left>-->
<?php get_template_part( 'sidebar_left' ); ?>
<!--</home left>-->
<!--</home 5>-->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Where exactly (in code) is the part that you refer to as "the content"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress don't have a function `show_content`. Content in wordpress is displayd using [`the_content()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content). The excerpt is  displayd using [`the_excerpt()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt). Just a point of note, move your `WP_Query` outside your `if` statement and change `if ( have_posts() )` to `if ( $wp_query->have_posts() )`

Comment: Im kinda new to this but i cant find the_exerpt() in this code. What will that change do?

Comment: Change `<?php echo excerpt(500); ?>` to `<?php the_content(); ?>`

Comment: How do I do that?